# Detect and handle a LaTeX warning/error generated via an os.system call in Python

Tags: python, error-handling, latex, sweave, os.system

I wrote a python script to automate turning Sweave/LaTeX documents into PDFs. Here's the most important part:

```
os.system("""echo "Sweave('%s.Rnw')" | R --vanilla --quiet"""%topic)

seq = ['p','b','p','b','p','p']
for op in seq: 
    if op is 'p':
        os.system('pdflatex %s'%topic)
    if op is 'b':
        os.system('bibtex %s'%topic)
    if op is 'l':
        os.system('latex %s'%topic)
```

This works great if there are no errors, but if there is a LaTeX error, I am brought to the CLI for LaTeX e.g.,

```
[10]
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in vertical mode.
l.625 #

?
```

I then need to break out of this manually. Is there a way that I can let Python "know" that the os.system call generated an error in LaTeX and then end this call but still capturing the error text?

Comment: did you find a way to capture the error text in Python?

Comment: yes - using pdftex_process = subprocess.Popen(['pdflatex', '-interaction=nonstopmode', '%s'%topic], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)     I can then access error messages by using the communicate() method on the pdftex_process object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Don't use `os.system`, use `subprocess` module instead.
2. `pdflatex` has an `-interaction` switch that you can use to put it a non-interactive mode (you probably want `batchmode` or `nonstopmode` IIRC, but you can experiment and see what each option do).

Comment: Yes, please use `subprocess` passing the arguments as a string array, using programs that use string interpolation like in the question can be very frustrating when they break for every third input.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `-interaction=nonstopmode` flag to LaTeX.